# Topic has no examples, still exists

Tags: bug, documentation

The topic [views and unmanaged models](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/django/1228/views-and-unmanaged-models) has no examples. As I understand it, a topic should be deleted if its last example is deleted or moved away. For some reason, this specific topic still exists, <s>and there seems to be no option to delete it.</s> There is a related improvement request, but this only shows the `Edit Topic` button, not the `Delete Topic` button.

---

On further investigation, it seems that you can delete the last example in a topic with deleting the topic itself. Moving all examples away warns you that this will delete the topic, and asks for additional confirmation, but there seems to be no such thing when deleting all examples.

Answer (score 2):

Click Edit title and then click the dustbin